# Procedures and lambda

Tags: scheme, procedures

```
(define (p-cons x y)
 (lambda (proc) (proc x y)))

(define (p-car proc)
(proc (lambda (p q) p)))

> (p-car(p-cons "foo" "bar"))
"foo"
```

How does this piece of code work?
This is a "homemade" version of cons and car in scheme.
I can't seem to understand why "p-cons" work.

```
(lambda (proc) (proc x y)))
(proc (lambda (p q) p)))
These two sentences makes no sense to me. 
How does (lambda (proc) (proc x y))) make it work as cons?
```

Answer (score 1):

This works by keeping all relevant state in closure variables. Consider

```
(define (p-cons x y)
  ;; "x" and "y" will be "closed over" and their values
  ;; are later available, whenever someone calls the 
  ;; anonymous lambda function, which we return here: 
  (lambda (accessor) 
    ;; Call the accessor, and pass all our hidden state
    ;; along. The accessor will select, whatever it needs,
    ;; and we simply return, whatever the accessor returned
    (apply accessor x y '())))

(define (p-car pseudo-cons)
  (apply pseudo-cons 
         ;; Is called by the "pseudo-cons" and receives the
         ;; full hidden state. Selects from it, what it wants
         ;; to return (here, the first "field")
         (lambda (state-x state-y) state-x) 
         '()))

(define (p-cdr pseudo-cons) 
  (apply pseudo-cons 
         ;; Is called by the "pseudo-cons" and receives the
         ;; full hidden state. Selects from it, what it wants
         ;; to return (here, the second "field")
         (lambda (state-x state-y) state-y) 
         '()))
```

Let's inspect things. When we do

```
(define some-p-cons (p-cons 1 2))
```

the value of `some-p-cons` is a procedure, which expects a single argument (of which we will talk later). More to the point, it is a "closure", which is a procedure, that has some hidden state. In our case, this hidden state consists of the `x` and `y` parameter values supplied to `p-cons`. Examples:

```
(p-cons 1 2)        ==> some procedure (hidden state x = 1 and y = 2)
(p-cons 'a 'b)      ==> some procedure (hidden state x = a and y = b)
(p-cons "hello" ()) ==> some procedure (hidden state x = "hello" and y = ())
```

Basically, `p-cons` acts like a record -- or it would, if there was a way to extract the hidden state somehow (otherwise, it would be a pretty useless record...)

That's where the single argument to the closure (named `accessor` above) comes into play. The accessor is called with the full hidden closure state (`x` and `y`) and selects, which of these values it wants to return. The `p-car` accessor returns the first (`x`) value, and the `p-cdr` accessor returns the second (`y`) value. Let's walk through this:

A call

```
(p-cons 1 2)
```

yields some object

```
#<closure (lambda (accessor) (accessor x y)) with hidden state x=1, y=2>
```

(notation made up on the spot). When we apply `p-car` to it

```
(p-car #<closure (lambda (accessor) (accessor x y)) with hidden state x=1, y=2>)
```

what happens is, that `p-car` will itself call the "pseudo-cons" (it's itself a procedure after all), passing along an accessor function, which selects the appropriate bits of the hidden state. The `p-car` functions does

```
(apply #<closure (lambda (accessor) (accessor x y)) with hidden state x=1, y=2>
       (lambda (state-x state-y) state-x)  ;; anonymous accessor function
       ())
```

Now, the ball's back at the "pseudo-cons" closure. It takes all it's hidden state, and passes it on to the accessor:

```
(apply (lambda (state-x state-y) state-x)  ;; anonymous accessor function
       x                                   ;; from hidden state, value is 1 in the example
       y                                   ;; from hidden state, value is 2 in the example
       ())
```

Bear with me, we are almost there... The accessor inspects the bits of state it got, and selects, whatever it wants to return. In the case of the `p-car` accessor, we want the value of the first field, and thus, that's what we return.

(The `apply` is not really necessary, but I find it clearer to make them explicit in this exposition)

We can even define a function, which turns our "pseudo conses" into real ones:

```
(define p-cons->pair (pcons)
  (apply pcons cons '()))
```

Here, we "abuse" the built-in procedure `cons` as our accessor function, which does not simply select one of its two arguments, but takes both and puts them into a regular scheme pair.